# Any way to add metaboxes in custom settings page of custom post type in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

Hi I would like to add metaboxes under custom settings page which is under a custom post type. I can create metaboxes for custom post types also I can create a theme options. But can't find any way to add the metaboxes on a custom settings page. Like my post type hierarchy is like below:
Products
 - All item
 - Add Item
 - Product Category
 - Product Settings

I want to add the metaboxes & create a options page on that settings page. Can you please guide me through this one.

I've been trying to follow this gist but can't find a way.
https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2-Snippet-Library/blob/master/options-and-settings-pages/theme-options-cmb.php

Also can you let me know if I can achieve something by tweaking this code where key|value operates

```
$cmb = new_cmb2_box( array(
    'id'      => $this->metabox_id,
    'hookup'  => false,
    'show_on' => array(
        // These are important, don't remove
        'key'   => 'options-page',
        'value' => array( $this->key, )
    ),
) );
```

I've created the settings page by this code

```
add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=ch_product_showcase', 'Product Showcase Settings', 'Showcase Settings', 'edit_posts', basename(__FILE__), array( $this, 'chProductShowcaseSettingsOptions') );
```

Comment: @mtinsley do you know the solution for this one?

Comment: Do not create metabox for settings. User add_option, update_option & get_option to full fill your requirement

Comment: thanks for the opinion... :) but metaboxes comes with a lot of options itselt that's why trying to use that option as settings. Just like a theme option by cmb2.

Comment: have you taken a look at how akismet creates meta boxes on their options page? I would guess looking at that code would provide the solution you are seeking. We just looked into this the other day, and when we go to build our meta box options pages, we will likely reference the Akismet plugin.

Comment: This article may help you: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/integrating-with-wordpress-ui-meta-boxes-on-custom-pages--wp-26843

Comment: And, here's another: http://admin-page-framework.michaeluno.jp/tutorials/09-add-a-meta-box-in-an-admin-page/

Comment: try https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/ plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done it many times.  Use this code and tweak it to your needs:

https://gist.github.com/turtlepod/5203512

Found as a link in the comments of this page:

https://gist.github.com/bueltge/757903

Originally posted here:

[Wordpress - Add meta box to options page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626844/wordpress-add-meta-box-to-options-page)

Normally I don't like answering with links to another site, but in this case the code is on gist and hopefully will never go away!